Set valued approximate inversion
I have a function $f: \mathcal{D} \to D$ where $\mathcal{D}$ is some domain of interest.
Now let function $g_\theta: \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{D})$ be a set valued function, Here $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{D})$ represents the power set of $\mathcal{D}$. The power set of $\mathcal{D}$ is the set of all subsets of $\mathcal{D}$. Here $g$ is a parametric function, parametrized by $\theta$.
We will find such a $g_\theta$ from two optimization problems, as outlined below.
PART I: Approximate set valued inversion
Now given some $x\in\mathcal{D}$, let $y = f(x)$.
Consider the optimization problem $\theta = \mathtt{arg min}_{\theta \in \Theta} \large \mathbb{E}_x \Large \| \enspace \mathbb{E}_{g_{\theta}(y)} \large{[}g_\theta(y)\large{]}  - \enspace x \enspace \Large{\|}$where $\mathbb{E}$ denotes expectation.
Then after solving for all $x\in \mathcal{D}$ (or many $x$ sampled from $\mathcal{D}$), some $g$ may be found. Such a g is an approximate set valued inversion of $f$. Is there a term for this, or reading material to read about such an operation in literature?
PART II: Projected set valued inversion
Now consider a variant of the above operation. Let $\Phi:\mathcal D \to \mathbb{R}^d$ where $\mathbb{R}$ refers to the reals. As before,
$f: \mathcal{D} \to D$ and $g: \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{D})$.
Again, given some $x\in\mathcal{D}$, let $y = f(x)$.
Consider the optimization problem $\theta = \mathtt{arg min}_{\theta \in \Theta} \large \mathbb{E}_x \Large \| \enspace \mathbb{E}_{g_\theta(y)} \large{[}\Phi(g_\theta(y))\large{]}  - \enspace \Phi(x) \enspace \Large{\|}$.
Is this well defined? Any references would be quite useful.
